# Is there any advantage to calculating the duration in MySQL as opposed to calculating duration in PHP (and then storing in MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql

**QUESTION:** Is there any advantage to calculating the duration in MySQL as opposed to calculating duration in PHP (and then storing in MySQL)?

I had intended on calculating duration for each time an activity is done. Duration would be calculated in PHP then inserted into a MySQL DB (along with other data such as start time, end time, user, activity, etc).

**But**, based on this question [Database normalization: How can I tabulate the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714567/database-normalization-how-can-i-tabulate-the-data) I got the impression that rather than record duration at the time of insert, I should calculate it based on the start and end values saved in the MySQL DB.

Does this sound right? If yes, can someone explain why? Are there any recommended ways of calculating duration for values stored in MySQL?

**EDIT:**

After a user completes an activity online, the start and finish time for that activity is inserted into the DB. I was going to use these values to calculate duration (either in MySQL or prior to insertion (using PHP). Duration would later be used for other calculations.

Comment: Duration of what? Is it something specific, or just between some 2 times/timestamps?

Comment: @Janis Peisenieks A user will do an activity. At the completion of the activity, the start and finish time will be inserted into the DB. I was going to use these values to calculate duration (either in MySQL or prior to insertion (using PHP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have a `start_time` and an `end_time` as basis for your `duration`, both of which will be stored in the database anyway? Then yes, there's hardly an advantage to storing the `duration` in the database as well. It's only duplicated data that you are storing already anyway (duration = end - start, which is a really quick calculation), so why store it again? Furthermore, that only allows for the data to go out of sync. Say some bug causes the `end_time` to be updated, but not the `duration`. Now you have inconsistent data with no real way to know which is correct.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are not going to need `end_time` in your calculations, you can store `start_time` and `duration` in the table, skipping `end_time`.

Comment: @ypercube I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that it depends on the size of the database, server load, etc... I have had instances where processing in PHP is faster, whereas other times processing in MySQL. There are lots of factors that could affect performance.

However, the thing to keep in mind is that you want to avoid multiple database calls. If you are going to try this in PHP, and loop through each record and do an update per record, I think that the number of mysql calls could hinder performance. However, if you calculate the duration in PHP prior to the insert, then it makes sense. If the data is already in the database, then perhaps a single update statement would be the best option.

Just my 2c

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wouldn't be updating the records. When a user completes an activity this causes a new entry to be inserted into the DB (in real time).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this depends mostly on the situation, so maybe add a little more details to your post in order to better understand what you're aiming at.

- If your program has alot of database-related actions, and the
  database server is slower than your PHP server, and it is about
  thousands and thousands of calculations, it may be better to
  calculate this in your PHP code.
- If your program doesn't leaves the
  database very much alone, and your code is already doing alot of
  work, maybe then it would be slightly better to let the database do
  the job.
- If you've already stored start- and end-time in your table,
  storing the duration would be a usually not necessary overhead (could
  be done anyway for the reason to improve performance if database
  space ain't an issue).

But, taking all of this into consideration, I don't think this decision is critical for most applications, it is most likely more a question of personal flavour and preference.

Comment: At this point in time, most of the work is being done in the code, but it's still early days though. I expect this will change later. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think, that it should be better to create 2 separate fields in MySQL rahter than calculate the duration in PHP.

And the reasons

- While it may be true, that MySQL will have to calculate it upon every retrieval, it is also true, that MySQL is very good at this. With a creation of a well made index, this should have no negative performance side-effects.
- It gives you more data to work with. Lets say, you want to find out when users finished their particular action. If you kept only the duration, you would have to calculate this time again, thus making it prone to errors. Keeping another date may come in handy.
- Also true, if you want to calculate some difference between activities of multiple users. In this case, a pre calculated value would be a pain in the a*s, since it would make you do more reverse calculations.

So in my opinion - add the separate fields. It is not a normalization problem, since you are not duplicating any data. Duration however would.

Comment: It seems that MySQL is the way to go. Thanks for reply :)